# Python - File I/O and execution time

Tags: python, file-io

When executing such commands in Python:

```
fd = open('some_file', 'r')

data = fd.read()

...

# use data now

...
```

what exactly is happening with data transfer? Is DMA applied here? If I want to "measure" the time needed until I use the data (for the first time) will it be like the following?

X msec from file to memory with DMA, Y msec from memory to CPU for use. `Total time == X + Y` `msec?` What exactly does Python do under the hood?

Comment: That depends a lot more on the operating system. Python, Cython at least will just be using the std C library functions to do I/O, fopen, fread, etc. It is up to the OS to do any optimization (readahead, caching, etc)

Comment: I see, so in the standard C library though the `data` variable is pre-defined like `int data;` for example. When I need the variable (e.g. `data++;`, let's say it is not cached, won't it be a transfer time from memory to CPU there? In the first place however, the data are transfered from the disk to memory (different initial transfer time) and exist there. Or not?

Answer (score 0):

Regular python file I/O is blocking (as the underlying C-Runtime implementations and or OS syscalls are blocking), meaning `fd.read()` will block until the data was actually retrieved by the OS and passed to python.

How caching, DMA and so on are handled is mostly up to the OS. You can however do stuff like [`posix_fadvise`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/posix_fadvise) yourself. Starting with Python 3.3, there is even [`os.posix_fadvise`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.posix_fadvise). For Python2 there are a bunch of third-party libraries implementing the same.

You also could simulate asynchronous I/O using threads, or find a third-party library that enables you to do asynchronous file I/O easily.

Comment: That was very enlightening. I was thinking the default behavior in a Linux system, though. If it is blocking, then CPU waits until data is received. So, when it is received, isn't it placed in memory until it is needed back from the CPU? I'm just reading a file, maybe I will need its data now, maybe not. Where does the data go first after reading them from the file? I hope it makes sense.

Comment: The question tell me that you should probably read a bit more about how operating systems work in general, and disk/file I/O in general... E.g. the CPU does not usually actively wait for I/O, at least not in common OSes. Simplified, the OS will mark the process (or more exactly the thread) waiting (iowait) and run something else in the mean time. But this is getting off-topic and too broad now.

Comment: Yes, there is an interrupt if I am correct. The disk "says" the data is ready for the cpu to use. The scheduler decides when the process is  running. So, when the process will run again, where will the data be in order for the process to use them? I'm insisting because I am not sure whether to bear in mind the time from memory to CPU + I/O to memory. Thank you anyway for your answer.

Comment: The data will be somewhere in memory (where memory does not necessarily mean RAM; the stuff could have been paged out again in the mean time). Where exactly depends on implementation that is usually removed at least a couple of abstraction layers from the python runtime and OS/platform specific. Point being: If you're taking about file I/O in python in general, there is no point in talking about highly platform/OS dependent implementation details like DMA, CPU, OS scheduler, OS paging strategy etc.

Comment: Just to be clear - blocking from the perspective of the python interpreter process. Very few things are truly blocking operations on most modern hardware and operating systems.